# GWT MVP. How to use event bus?

Tags: java, gwt

In project I use MVP pattern. I have 2 view and 2 corresponding presenters. From "`Presenter2`" i want to get selected value in "`View1`". What is the best way to do it? I know that better to use event bus. But so i must to create 2 events and 2 event handlers (1st event will rise when Presenter2 need selected value from `View1`, and it will be handled in `Presenter1.` 2nd event will rise in `Presenter1` (like: `new selectedValueEvent(value)` to notificate Presenter2 about selected value. So Presenter2 will handle `selectedValueEvent(value)` and get `value`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the point when the presenter needs to get the selected value is when the user makes an action you won't get around using an event. (Altough, maybe both presenters could react to the same event so don't need to use two different ones?)

If it is known when the presenter needs to get the value (a defined step in a workflow), you could to it like this:

Keep a reference to the views in the `ClientFactory`:

```
public class ClientFactoryImpl implements ClientFactory {
    private static final EventBus eventBus = new SimpleEventBus();
    /* The views */
    private static final SampleView sampleView = new SampleView(); 
    ....

    public ClientFactoryImpl(){
        eventBus.addHandler(ReleaseAddedEvent.type, sampleView);
        ....
    }


    // getter and setters
}
```

So in the Presenter you can get a reference to the view: `SampleView view = MyEntryPoint.getClientFactory().getSampleView();` and then you can just call a method from the view which returns the selected value.

Comment: Yes, in my App I use clientFactory. And now It worked how you wrote (getting another (not corresponding to this presenter) View and calling on this View getSelected() method).. But I think creating reference in Presenter to not corresponding View is not good idea.. Or not?

Comment: If you just create a local reference in a method in the presenter it should not be a problem since the local reference only exists as long as this method is executed.